# How to compile python code for 2.x from 3.x

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to compile python code for target 2.7 from a 3.2 script.

Below works fine for compiling. But on execution I obviously get a "Bad magic number error" because compile & target python versions are different.

```
for fn in os.listdir(source):
    srcfile = ...
    ...
    destfile = ... + ".pyc"
    #print(srcfile, destfile)
    py_compile.compile(srcfile, destfile)   # <--
```

Is it possible without executing 2.7 python from within 3.2? Is there a way to mention target version?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Python 2.7 is embedded in a C++ product. But build process exists in 3.2. Now, the python code (2.7) that ships with the product must be compiled so that end users don't easily read/change it. Hope that answers.

Comment: This doesn't answer why you don't want to fork out to Python 2.7.

Comment: Have to install python 2.7 (as well) on build machines.

Comment: How are you building the embedded C++ product without having Python 2.7 already on the build machines?

Comment: You don't need python.exe to embedd python. It gets packed as python27.dll with other exes.

Comment: @sambha: If your build machines are Linux or OSX-based, Python 2.7 is in all likelihood already installed on them.

Comment: @Max - Windows unfortunately! The biggest issue (rather than a technical one) is that all developers have to have Python 2.7 & 3.2 on their machines.

Comment: @sambha: Where does that `python27.dll` come for, or the header and config files used to build your embedded app, if not from Python 2.7?

Comment: @abarnert: python27.dll comes as a third party library. It comes to the developer machine from source control. The point I want to make is that python is embedded into the product - it runs in the product process. It does not have to be installed on the machine. Hope it clarifies my situation.

Comment: @sambha: Sure, but it doesn't have to be installed on the target machine for your extensions to work either. It just has to be installed on the build machine for your extensions to build. Just like it has to be installed on the build machine for the application to build. If you're using different build machines for the extensions and the application, then you will need to have a Python 2.7 development environment on the extension build machines. There's really no way around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPython binary can't cross-compile for a different Python version.  You are probably best off by forking out to a Python interpreter with the desired target version and using the [compileall](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/compileall.html) module directly from the command-line.

Comment: Forking 2.7 from 3.2 seems to be the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) function, modules like [`compileall`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html) and [`ast`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), etc. all just expose the parser and compiler that are baked into each Python version. Python 3.2 doesn't have a compiler for 2.7 code.

And if you were expecting to compile 3.2 code into 2.7 bytecode… that's not even possible, in general, so obviously Python 3.2 can't do it.

You could try to port all of the 2.7 compiler machinery to Python—PyPy would be a good source to start from—and then run that under 3.2. But that's a lot of work just to avoid installing Python 2.7 alongside 3.2.